# two column of data in one chart Excel

Tags: excel

my data set is more that 1 billion rows, hence I should keep it in 2 column. I would like to create a bar chart based on them.

for example my data is (the data are in one column)

- 5
- 40
- 80
- 50
- 30
- 10

and the bar chart like following [image: bar char based on above data]

now my data are divided in two columns

**column A**

- 5
- 40
- 80

**column B**

- 50
- 30
- 10

how can I reach to same bar chart ?

thanks.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but isn't an Excel worksheet limited to 1,048,576 rows? Furthermore, may I suggest that Excel may not be the best tool for this scale?

Comment: yes, it is not good for this scale but it is easiest way for plotting my code's result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing would be to create your bar chart from column A, then go in and edit the series data.

Click on the chart and where it says:

```
=SERIES(,,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$30000,1)
```

Change it to:

```
=SERIES(,,(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$30000,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3000000),1)
```

Also, I do hope you have much less than a billion rows.

Comment: thanks, actually my data more than 2 billion and I divided in two columns